# Are the perpetual machines in this video really perpetual?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, perpetual-motion

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=287qd4uI7-E&list=TLKck2toHQ5E0Jr3xjm9w2qBzOVIHrfNB-) lists a number of perpetual motion machines that have been proposed throughout history:

- [Robert Boyle's Self-Flowing Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBoyle%27sSelfFlowingFlask.png)
- [A "perpetual train" using rolling cones](http://blog.modernmechanix.com/can-trains-be-run-by-perpetual-motion/)
- [F. G. Woodward's hoop wheel machine](http://englishclassperpetualmotion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/fg-woodward-machine.html)
- [Jacob Leupold’s Overbalanced Wheel](http://jamesminshall.com/sustainability/energy-generation/perpetual-motion-generators/)
- [Bob Schadewald’s Wheel](http://jamesminshall.com/sustainability/energy-generation/perpetual-motion-generators/)
- [Villard's wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPerpetuum_mobile_villard_de_honnecourt.jpg)

These are all mechanical machines, which use gravity to operate, i.e, they are a way to transform the force of gravity into energy, and do not need batteries or motors. Since I think that those machines are not really perpetual motion ones, can they turn for hundreds of years or will it stop just after some minutes?

Comment: They will stop when the batteries run out - each one has a hidden pump or motor, that's all.

Comment: @Nathaniel Those machines do not violate the current laws of physics, instead, they try to use the force of gravity.

Comment: Trust me, the ones in that video have hidden motors. (Apart from the perpetual train, where if you watch the weight rather than the slope it's on, you'll see it just rolls downhill for a bit then stops.) The thing that all those proposed machines have in common is that they don't work. Friction very rapidly stops them from turning.

Comment: @Nathaniel What about *Jacob Leupold’s Overbalanced Wheel* and *Boyle's Self-Flowing Flask*, isn't it a way to convert the force of gravity into energy?

Comment: @Nathaniel Or not?

Comment: Hi @Adobe, sorry I forgot about your comment. The thing is, a force can't really be converted into energy, because they are different things, with different units. Gravitational potential (which is force times distance) can be converted into energy, but only by moving mass downwards. If you want to return the mass to where it was you have to move it up again, which uses up the same amount of energy as you gained by moving it down. This is why those devices won't really turn like that: the energy gained by moving mass down on one side cancels the energy lost by moving it back up on the other.

Comment: @Nathaniel But those moving mass of the top are also subject to gravity, so the total energy generated will not be $0$.

Comment: you generate $mgh$ of energy for each weight you move from the top to the bottom, but you pay $mgh$ to get it back to the top again. So the total is $0$, always. It doesn't matter how they're connected or how they move, this will always be true. The impossibility of ever getting a non-zero amount of energy from such a machine is one of the most fundamental laws of physics there is.

Comment: @Nathaniel So how to produce energy from gravity?

Comment: @Adobe One can use gravity to store energy, as in dams on rivers and waterfalls (rain naturally, pumping it up for storage of  energy for example with electricity from sunlight). Ultimately all the energy we find methods to produce and use has come from sunlight: food for live organisms and wood, oil and coal. In the twentieth century we found a way to get the energy from the nucleus which was stored when those nuclei were generated in supernovae or the big bang (fusion elements). Energy transforms from one for to another, it is not created.

Comment: Quit squabbling and build one to see if it works and how long it goes. The flask is probably the most legitimate one and the easiest to make. But you skeptics will not believe it unless you see it yourself or, it gets labeled as evolution. That one word makes people believe what they have never and will never see for themselves. This, however, is something you can experiment with and find out for your self.

Comment: It's blatantly impossible for one of these things to work. Just look at @Srichakradhar 's answer.

Comment: @Nathaniel What are you talking about? We get non-zero amounts of energy from these types of machines all the time. After all, negative is still non-zero.... Definition: "Technically Correct": adj. 1. Being of the highest level or best kind of truth and/or factuality; the best kind of correct. 2. see Jim.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) describes Perpetual motion as motion that continues indefinitely 
without any external source of energy. This is impossible in practice because of friction 
and other sources of energy loss.

Of course, this is practically impossible since you can never fully eliminate the
frictional forces. Although we say it’s impossible, people still like to come up with 
ideas. Perpetual motion machines are sort of like playing the lottery. People think they 
have a much higher chance of winning than their actual chance of winning.

Perpetual motion describes motion that continues indefinitely without any external 
source of energy is impossible in practice because of friction and other sources of 
energy loss. It violates the first or second law of thermodynamics.

See this detailed [explanation](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2012/11/an-analysis-of-a-perpetual-motion-machine/) at wired.com with a kind of experimentation.

Comment: Those machines do not violate the current laws of physics, instead, they try to use the force of gravity. And we can eliminate frictional forces with super-fluids.

Comment: `instead, they try to use the force of gravity` Force does not equal energy. You need room to do work. That is the fundamental law they're trying to break. `And we can eliminate frictional forces with super-fluids.`. `ELIMINATE`? Tell me again, how we can eliminate friction...

Comment: The Wikipedia page @Srichakradhar linked to actually mentions why superfluids (and other seeming solutions to friction) don't work.  And no one is saying they "violate the laws of physics", we're saying they're not perpetual motion machines.